# sql Dependency detect changes of records and send message to clients

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to use sql Dependency to check that a table data has been changed by other clients I followed the turotial here but when I try to create the queue i get the following error message this is my c# code and sql statement.

**Edit 1**
Sorry I forgot to include the tutorial in my first post here is the link in the tutorial it states quename but does not say how to ccreate it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

> CREATE QUEUE ExportedOrdersChangeMessage   CREATE SERVICE
>   ExportedOrdersService ON QUEUE ExportedOrdersChangeMessage
>   ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notification/PostQueryNotification])

The error I receive after running the above is the following.

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   c'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notification/PostQueryNotification',
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Basically what I want to be able to do is if a user is atempting to change a record I want to send a notification to the other clients. Is this the best method for this approach its a winforms business app if any other libarys that make this easier would be great.

I am using sql Server 2017 express which I asumes would have this as standard?.

```
private void DetectChanges()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.  

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create a new SqlCommand object.  
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT exportedtoMeteor FROM dbo.exported", con))
        {
            // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.  
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            // Maintain the reference in a class member.  
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, "ExportedOrdersChangeMessage");

            // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.  
            dependency.OnChange += new
                OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

            // Execute the command.  
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Process the DataReader.  
            }
        }
    }
}

// Handler method  
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).  
}

void Termination()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    // Release the dependency.  
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, ExportedHacket);
}
```

Comment: What tutorial is it you followed? You said "here" but then didn't supply a link; apart from those your your code/error (which also means you haven't supplied the SQL you used), but those are dead links.

Comment: Tutorial link added above thanks for that just forgot to add it at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer to your direct question but [Butterfly Server .NET](https://butterflyserver.io) detects changes to databases (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, MS SQL Server, etc) and allows creating Dynamic Views based on SELECT statements that publish events if the SELECT results change.  There are caveats (like all database operations have to be performed via the IDatabase interface provided by Butterfly Server .NET).  However, it's similar enough to what you are doing that you may be interested.

Comment: This isn't helpful at all. This more spam than anything.